# Ruby - How to get the last two values in an array?

Tags: ruby

```ruby
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

numbers.last
# => 8
```

I need to grab the last two records.

So far I've tried this:

```ruby
numbers.last - 1
# throws a `NoMethodError`
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`last` takes an argument:

```
@numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
@numbers.last(2) # => [7,8]
```

If you want to remove the last two items:

```
@numbers.pop(2) #=> [7, 8]
p @numbers #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: +1, this is something I always completely forget for some reason, although it reads a lot friendlier than the index version...

Answer (score 18):

Arrays are defined using `[]` not `{}`. You can use negative indices and ranges to do what you want:

```
>> @numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>> @numbers.last #=> 8
>> @numbers[-2..-1] #=> [7, 8]
```

Comment: It should be noted, that ranges starting with negative bound **FAIL**, if the array contains less than given number of items, so:
`@numbers[-9..-1] #=> nil`, instead of returning the existing 8 elements. `last` is much more well-behaved in this regard. `@numbers.last(9)` would return the 8 element array.